# RewriteRule started returning 403 Forbidden error

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, 403-forbidden

I have a website that uses a set of quite simple RewriteRules of the format:

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /product.php?$1 [L]
```

All was working well and still is working perfectly fine on localhost. For some reason, without me making any changes, those pages have started returning a 403 Forbidden error.

The problem seems to be spaces (encoded as %20) in the url query string. Looking in the logs shows this error

> [rewrite:error] [pid xxxx:tid xxxxxxxxxxxxxx] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx] AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control characters or spaces

Sure enough, `example.com/p/parameter%20name=value` gives a 403 whereas `example.com/p/parameterName=value` doesn't.

Just adding spaces to a query string on a page that has a rewrite rule that doesn't use the query string doesn't cause an error.
e.g. the rule `RewriteRule ^contact-us/$ /contact.php [L]` doesn't have a problem with the url `example.com/contact-us/?query%20string=value`

I'm aware that using + instead of %20 is a possibility or not using spaces at all. Both are not very practical options at the moment and using %20 was perfectly fine until about a day ago.

I can't see any permissions issues anywhere either.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

**UPDATE:**

As Mr White points out in his answer, the trick here is to make sure the `B` flag is set on the Rewrite rules in htaccess.

Because I am accessing the full query string using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` I then needed to use `urldecode` as well.

This then returns the same output that I used to get before the Apache update.

Comment: What version of Apache are you running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For some reason, without me making any changes, those pages have started returning a 403 Forbidden error.

It's likely the version of Apache has been updated on your server.

[I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75685188/369434) [a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite) just yesterday. This would seem to be a bug (IMO) in a recent version of Apache (2.4.56-1 / 2.4.52-1 ?), although this has also been cited as a "security fix" in the other answer on that question.

The "solution" is to use the `B` (*escape backreferences*) flag on your rule, to URL encode the (unencoded) backreference before it is used in the *substitution* string. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /product.php?$1 [B,L]
```

(Presumably this URL-encodes the *space* as `+`, as opposed to `%20` - which is what "normally" happens.)

Arguably, you should perhaps be using the `B` flag anyway here, although this depends on what other "special" characters you are expecting. eg. Without the `B` flag, a request of the form `/p/param=v&lue` would not be rewritten correctly since the `&` would not be URL encoded and the parameter value in the query string would effectively be *broken*.

However, you shouldn't *need* to use the `B` flag if all you are expecting is *spaces*. mod_rewrite (should) automatically URL encode an "invalid" *substitution* string. In this case the *space* should be URL encoded as `%20` - which is perfectly valid, but now breaks with an error. In fact, it has been reported that even manually rewriting to `%20` in the query string also breaks with this error. For example:

```
# Now breaks with error "AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control characters or spaces"
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar?q=one%20two [L]
```

The above is *not* invalid, but is now deemed to be.

(DISCLAIMER: I've not been able to test this myself yet.)

I'm not sure exactly what this "security fix" is meant to resolve (if indeed it is intentional), but it is certainly a breaking change that is affecting many sites. It also now invalidates several examples in the official Apache docs, which makes me think this is more of a "bug" than a "fix".

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite

Comment: This is a great answer and very informative. I will test this out asap. For the record, I tried using the B flag but that broke my local version so didn't try it on the live server but will do that now.

Comment: @JimboVader How did the `B` flag break your local version? What URL were you requesting? What Apache version are you running locally and on the live server?

Comment: I've just upgraded apache on my local server and that now has the same 403 issue so it looks like you are correct on the cause of the issue. The problem now is that when using the B flag, getting the query string using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] returns something different from before. By that, I mean my functions for processing it don't work. However, currently investigating exactly what is different and will report back...

Comment: @JimboVader The only thing that I would expect to be different is that _spaces_ in the query string are now encoded as `+` and not `%20` (which is a perfectly valid encoding in the query string) and this will be reflected in the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` superglobal. However, if you are accessing the URL params via the `$_GET` superglobal then you should not notice any difference since this is already URL-decoded (whereas the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` superglobal is not).

Comment: Correct again, after adding the B flag I then need to urldecode the query string and all seems to work again.