# AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control characters or spaces

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, 403-forbidden

How to reproduce the error:
-- A space in my URL will trigger the error.

Observation of the error:
-- It seems to happen suddenly since around 3/10.
---- I did not upgrade my Apache version, but it seems like the `-1ubuntu4.27` package was being auto-installed (There are related messages on the `/var/log/dpkg.log`.).
-- On browser: 403 Forbidden error.
-- On Apache error log: it gets the `AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control characters or spaces` error.

Potential solution:
I found two references, user @MrWhite suggested using the `B` flag on `RewriteRule`. It does work for my server.

**My question:**
-- Precisely, is it that particular package causing the error?
-- Does this problem only happen to `RewriteRule`?
-- Is there a universal fix? I mean if I have multiple applications, instead of changing each of their `RewriteRule`, is it possible to make correction one time and the fix can be applied to the entire server?

Related reference:
-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite
-- [RewriteRule started returning 403 Forbidden error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141824/rewriterule-started-returning-403-forbidden-error)

Comment: I think that the answer is already in your first link which points to [security-fix](https://github.com/apache/httpd/commit/d78a166fedd9d02c23e4b71d5f53bd9b2c4b9a51).  So I don't know how to flag it.

Comment: Which directives specifically are you having a problem with? And where exactly? What URLs (and range of characters) are you expecting?

Comment: @MrWhite:

Thank you for your reply. I would like to first answer your questions:

Which directives and where:
Sorry if I misunderstand your question please correct me. As far as I can tell it seems any URL that has space and if it is being requested from browser, it will cause the error.
If you meant directory path, they are under `/var/www/html/`.

Range of characters:
Beside space, I don't know if other characters are having this new problem. I have a feeling that probably more characters are being affected; because I tested some other URL special characters and some of them fail.

Comment: @MrWhite:
(Continuing my last message.)
Before this problem occurs, there is almost zero problem from all URLs that my server processes. I will need to compare the result of my updated server and my offline server to confirm if some of the URL special characters are being affected by this Apache upgrade.

I read your reply from the other question. I have the same doubt, I need more study to find out precisely what kind of security problem does this upgrade package "fix".

Comment: @MrWhite:  Based on a search result that I found, I assume before this upgrade, "invalid query string" is being forwarded?

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by Rohit Gupta in a comment, there was a change to Apache2 outlined in [this git pull request](https://github.com/apache/httpd/commit/d78a166fedd9d02c23e4b71d5f53bd9b2c4b9a51), I just had to change my `RewriteRules` to include the [`B`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) and [`BNP`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_bnp) flags.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 "[L,QSA,B= ?,BNP]"
```

The old `RewriteRule` did not include that `B` and `BNP` entries. The `BNP` may not be necessary for your service. It makes sure to use `%20` instead of `+` for the space (i.e. NP as No Plus).

Make sure you change all the `RewriteRule` in this way.

> **IMPORTANT NOTE:**
>
> *The quotation is important in that case because a space delimits parameters by default. In other words:*
>
> ```
> [L,QSA,B= ?,BNP]
> ```
>
> *would be viewed as*
>
> ```
> [L,QSA,B=
> ```
>
> *and*
>
> ```
> ?,BNP]
> ```
>
> *and obviously Apache2 would fail to load that.*

Answer (score 0):

Try replace spaces with +

Add the following after

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1+$2 [L,R=301]
```

in main .htaccess

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).